# Dealing with ambiguity in bison

Tags: bison

https://pastebin.com/eMAJA9RV

I am working with the Bison grammar in the above link (its part of a forked copy of an older version of the open source flasm project and I wont go into details of why I am modifying it)

Using this I get the following error on one of my files:
Ambiguity detected.

```
Option 1,
  statements -> <Rule 116, tokens 509 .. 516>
    statements -> <Rule 113, tokens 509 .. 514>
      statements <tokens 509 .. 512>
      statement -> <Rule 127, tokens 513 .. 514>
        opcode -> <Rule 301, tokens 513 .. 514>
          PUSH <tokens 513 .. 513>
          @24 -> <Rule 300, empty>
          push_list -> <Rule 217, tokens 514 .. 514>
            push_item -> <Rule 178, tokens 514 .. 514>
              STRING <tokens 514 .. 514>
    statementOptimized -> <Rule 128, tokens 515 .. 516>
      opcodeOptimized -> <Rule 254, tokens 515 .. 516>
        CALLMETHOD <tokens 515 .. 515>
        POP <tokens 516 .. 516>

Option 2,
  statements -> <Rule 116, tokens 509 .. 516>
    statements <tokens 509 .. 512>
    statementOptimized -> <Rule 128, tokens 513 .. 516>
      opcodeOptimized -> <Rule 238, tokens 513 .. 516>
        PUSH <tokens 513 .. 513>
        STRING <tokens 514 .. 514>
        CALLMETHOD <tokens 515 .. 515>
        POP <tokens 516 .. 516>
```

I have tried various combinations of the dprec operator on the various rules involved but I cant find a combination that works. How can I somehow get the bison parser to favor option 2 anytime it sees that combination instead of complaining that its unable to decide which one to use?

For reasons I wont go into, I am stuck using Bison 2.1 for this project so whatever solution I need has to work with that version of Bison.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a simple solution here, regardless of Bison version. You can't use `%dprec` because the ambiguity is between two different applications of the same rule. You can't use `%merge` because both possible productions' action functions are evaluated before calling the custom merge function, which is fatal in a one-pass compiler.

It would be useful to know what change you made led to this issue. You can probably special-case that particular change, but I suspect that the only scalable change is to separate peephole optimisation into a post-parse phase.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
statements : 
     statement                        {   $$ = $1;        } %dprec 5
   | statements statement             {   $$ = $1 + $2;   } %dprec 1
   | statementOptimized               {   $$ = $1;        } %dprec 20
   | statementScanned                 {   $$ = $1;        } %dprec 15
   | statements statementOptimized    {   $$ = $1 + $2;   } %dprec 10
   | statements statementScanned      {   $$ = $1 + $2;   } %dprec 8
   ;
```

Try:

```
one_or_more_generic_statements:
    generic_statement ';'
  | one_or_more_generic_statements generic_statement ';'

generic_statement :
    statement          %dprec 1
  | statementScanned   %dprec 2
  | statementOptimized %dprec 3
```

I am not 100% sure this will resolve the ambiguity error (since no input was provided that would trigger the error,apologies in advance if this isn't the fix). To support my case on why this might be the fix, the article on [using glr to resolve ambiguities](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Merging-GLR-Parses.html) provides one such example where the ambiguous block is "wrapped" in it's own nonterminal.